# How to add/ignore a subfolder in htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have build an app at `http://url/sdf19/`

I have a .htaccess placed in /sdf19/ containing RewriteRule for clean urls.

But I have built a PDF generating tool, which is in a subfolder `/inc/tools`.
I need to link to it direct to run before headers.

Despite a few hours of searching, trying snippets, generators, etc. I cannot get any request to `http://url/sdf19/inc/tools` to be allowed, without the existing RewriteRule set taking over

Here is my starting file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC]
```

I've tried to add this on line 4;
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^ inc/tools/ [NC]`
This gave RewriteCond: bad argument line error

I've tried to add this to line 2;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/inc/tools/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
```

Desired result is that I can allow direct access to `http://url/sdf19/inc/tools` > everything I have tried so far i get redirected to base `http://url/sdf19/`

Comment: Try adding this rule at the beginning of your `.htaccess` file: `RewriteRule ^(inc)($|/) - [L]`

Comment: @Hackerman no luck, I'm afraid. spits me straight back to `/sdf19`.  in the Network log in the Console I can see the browser hit the `/inc/tools/pdf.php` with a 302 status for a split second before the redirect.

Comment: Thanks @Emma -- have done so over there now, again, most snippets & answers provide things I seem to have tried, so I hope with my particular .htaccess on show, someone can save me from insanity

Comment: Cross-site post on ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/questions/967977/how-to-add-ignore-a-subfolder-in-htaccess-file

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, we could step by step solve this problem. First step, we might just want to make something work with as less as boundaries that'd be possible.

Let's design a [low boundary expression](https://regex101.com/r/77SnGJ/1), maybe something similar to:

```
(.+)(\/inc\/tools)
```

From here, we can just add `\/inc\/tools` to the `RewriteCond`, just for testing. Later, we can modify that.

---

#### RegEx

If this wasn't a desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/77SnGJ/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### RewriteRule Test

You can test your RewriteRules in [htaccess.madewithlove.be](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

I'm not so sure about the rest of RewriteRules, but I'm assuming they are working fine and not conflicting with the new one. Maybe, this or something similar would work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/inc\/tools  [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC]

</IfModule>
```